# Is it possible to identify a fault on the network through software?

Tags: networking

Is there a tool which sends a packet through the wire and reports back each station or when it time outs? Sort of like a more detailed version of tracert on Windows. The reason being that I suspect there is a fault somewhere on our ADSL telephone line but have no way to find out.

Comment: What made you suspect the phone line having issue? If your telephone line is having issue, one easy way to test is to pick up a phone attached to that line and listen for any noise / crackling noise / strange hissing noise. Or you can call up your telephone company and ask them to do testing. I don't know where you are, but in Australia, if we call them out for testing, and there are fault on the line, they cover the call out fee. If there are no fault, then the customer pay the call out fee.

Comment: A well known program which does this is "Nagios".  I have not put it in as an answer as its designed for Unix systems and requires quite a lot of configuration.

Comment: @davidgo Zoredache seems to be saying that this is impossible...?

Comment: He is correct. I misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not any generic tool to do this.

The answer basically goes back to the OSI or IP networking model.

From a IP connected machine:

- You can see messages about physical issues for the directly connected network up to the nearest switch/router.
- You can troubleshoot Ethernet (link) layer up to your local router.
- Once you hit a router you can only get data at the networking layer.

If you want to troubleshoot beyond your local machine you would need to get some kind of admin access to the devices physically connected to that link.

So to troubleshoot your DSL link you would need some kind of admin diagnostic access to your DSL modem or devices on ISPs network, which you probably do not have.

If you suspect wiring issues within your local building on a DSL like, then move your modem to the phone companies demarc point.  There is usually a port you can plug a line into as it enters the structure.  If you still have problems beyond that point, then it is beyond your control.  Call your phone company/ISP.